# Copying text files containing Cyrillic to a different destination using a batch script

Tags: character-encoding, batch-file

I have a number of text files I'm looking to send to different destinations depending on whether or not the file contains Cyrillic characters using a batch script. For example:

```
All Files are  located in C:\mydocs. The script will be monitoring this file.

File one: contains all English characters > copy to C:\mydocs\English\
File two: Contains some Cyrillic characters > copy to C\mydocs\Contains_Cyrillic\
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your text file is encoded. If the file is unicode, then I'm not sure how to test.

But if the file is extended ascii (1 byte per character), then the meaning of bytes > decimal 127 is dependent on the code page. You can't really tell if the file contains Cyrillic, but you can tell if it contains a byte >127 which is likely to be a non-English character.

The following script should work on Windows XP and later - no need to download anything.

It first creates a file that is >= the length of your file, consisting only of the character "A". Then it uses FC to do a binary comparison and pipes the result to FINDSTR which looks for a value >= 0x80. If one is found, then it returns ERRORLEVEL 1, else it returns ERRORLEVEL 0.

```
@echo off
call :HasExtendedASCII %1 && (echo English) || echo Not English
exit /b

:HasExtendedASCII
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "tempFile=%temp%\dummyFile%random%.txt"
<nul set /p "=A" >"!tempFile!"
set /a dummySize=1
for /l %%N in (1 1 32) do if !dummySize! lss %~z1 (set /a dummySize*=2 & type "!tempFile!" >>"!tempFile!")
fc /b "!tempFile!" %1|findstr /re " [89ABCDEF][0123456789ABCDEF]" >nul&& set rtn=1 || set rtn=0
del "!tempFile!"
exit /b %rtn%
```

Comment: This seems promising, but unfortunately the files are in unicode. If I convert them to ascii first using the TYPE command will this still work?

Comment: @bniedermeyer - I would not recommend it. You would have to make sure you have the correct code page set when you use TYPE to convert to extended ASCII. It would be much safer to use a tool that can process unicode directly.  I have read that the FIND command supports unicode, but I've never seen any documentation that shows how to search unicode. I recommend you investigate VBScript or JScript. Or perhaps PowerShell has some unicode capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy as the cmd works only over the extended ascii table.
Here is a file that contains the cyrillic alphabet printed with `type` command:
`тхЁЄ·єшюярёфЇуїщъыч№Ўцсэьў∙°■╫▐┘╪▀┬┼╨╥┌╙╚╬╧└╤─╘├╒╔╩╦╟▄╓╞┴═╠` (bulgarian cyrillic- may differs with russian , mongolian and etc...)

unfortunately `FINDSTR` command does not work well with these.
BUT  IF  the only specaial characters that these files contains are cyrillic may be there's a chance :-).You can check the cyrillic characters by their HEX codes.There's a `certutil` [command that you can use to encode a file to hex](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1562) , or dump it to hex.Not win xp native but it can be downloaded from microsoft.com .Here are the hex codes:

```
ff e2 e5 f0 f2 fa f3 e8 ee ef e0 f1 e4 f4 e3 f5   
e9 ea eb e7 fc f6 e6 e1 ed ec f7 f9 f8 fe d7 de   
d9 d8 df c2 c5 d0 d2 da d3 c8 ce cf c0 d1 c4 d4   
c3 d5 c9 ca cb c7 dc d6 c6 c1 cd cc
```

and here's the code:

```
@echo off
certutil -dump my.cirillyc.file | findstr /r ""ff" "e2" "e5" "f0" "f2" "fa" "f3" "e8" "ee" "ef" "e0" "f1" "e4" "f4" "e3" "f5" "e9" "ea" "eb" "e7" "fc" "f6" "e6" "e1" "ed" "ec" "f7" "f9" "f8" "fe" "d7" "de" "d9" "d8" "df" "c2" "c5" "d0" "d2" "da" "d3" "c8" "ce" "cf" "c0" "d1" "c4" "d4" "" "c3" "d5" "c9" "ca" "cb" "c7" "dc" "d6" "c6" "c1" "cd" "cc""

if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    copy my.cirillyc.file  C\mydocs\Contains_Cyrillic\
)
```

May not work so properly if you file contains some of ╓╞┴═╠... symbols but should be ok in the more cases.To traverse all files in a directory you can surround the this with `for /f` loop

Comment: I will have to do some research and see if I have certutil on this machine. If I do I'll try it out and report back. Thanks